# Removing specific set of square brackets from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am currently receiving:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "shipments",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "shipment_tracking_number": "TRACK007",
                "shipment_carrier": "AusPost",
                "line_items_ids": [
                    1,
                    2
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to remove the outer set of square brackets, such that the above is formatted like so:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "shipments",
        "attributes": {
            "shipment_tracking_number": "TRACK007",
            "shipment_carrier": "AusPost",
            "line_items_ids": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This JSON object has been parsed from a csv file with the following:

```
...
dfpush = dfall[['shipment_tracking_number','shipment_carrier','line_items_ids']].where(df['invoice_id'] == uniquevalue)
dfpush = dfpush.dropna(subset='shipment_tracking_number')
dfjson = dfpush.to_dict('records')
jsonpush = json.dumps({"data":{"type": "shipments", "attributes": dfjson }}, indent=4)
```

Would ideally like to not be merely fixing the errant pair of square brackets but to have it formatted correctly in the first place (if not too difficult to achieve) but struggling to even get the brackets to behave with less clean methods.

Comment: `"attributes": dfjson[0]` instead of `"attributes": dfjson`?

Comment: @Tranbi I swear I tried that but earlier but it 100% works

Comment: Are you sure you want to only get the first object inside an array?  From the code snippet it seems like you are trying to get list of shipments under a given invoice. Getting the first object might mean that you will lose other shipments (if there are multiple shipments under one invoice)

Comment: I should've posted more code, I have a for loop as I need to process & post shipment per order. Would be much easier if the API allowed for multiple shipments to be submitted via the one endpoint
```
for uniquevalue in df['invoice_id'].unique():
    etc
```